ModuleNotFoundError: No module named when trying to run python programs from command line
Any time I try to run a program that uses python from the command line I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error. I have tried to open carla by just running carla in the command line and get.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla", line 22, in <module>
    from carla_host import *
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla_host.py", line 40, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

And I just tried to open cameractls by doing ./cameractrlsgtk4.py and got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevek/Downloads/cameractrls/./cameractrlsgtk4.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

I am on ubuntu 24.04 and the python version I have installed is Python 3.12.4 (main, Jun  6 2024, 18:26:44) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux . Not sure what is happening here but it is pretty annoying. Any help would be appreciated. I can open carla just fine from the launcher icon but not from comand line. If you need more info let me know in the comments.

I only see python3 version 3.12.3 for Ubuntu 24.04 - did you install 3.12.4 manually somehow?

sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 python3-gi should fix both (I'm not entirely sure about the second one); if more unmet dependencies come up after installing those, you'll have to figure out which package provides them and install it, rinsing and repeating until the programs run. In general, it'ìs expected for a standard installation to not include any possible library right away

@steeldriver I didn't install python3.12.4. But for some reason that seems to be the version being used. I just tried sudo apt install python3 and I got the following output python3 is already the newest version (3.12.3-0ubuntu1). So it seems that apt has installed 3.12.3 but somehow I am using 3.112.4.

@kos sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 python-gi-dev did not fix the issue. I still get the same result.

Did you install a 3rd party python like anaconda or miniconda?

@steeldriver no not that I'm aware of.

I mistyped python3-gi-dev for python3-gi, please try that as well, however I'd have expected sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 to fix at least the first issue...

@kos I get the following output python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.15.10+dfsg-1build6) so its already installed

If I had to guess, then environment issue, the library is there but your script can't include it. Maybe. But some Python / virtual environment expert should chime in cause I wouldn't know how to fix that off the top of my head (if that's the issue at all).

The output of type -a python python3 may help figure out what's going on (please [edit] it into your question rather than posting in comments)

@steeldriver here is the output python not found python3 is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3 python3 is /usr/bin/python3 python3 is /bin/python3

@steeldriver So i saw that python3 was installed by brew from the command you had me type in your last comment. I uninstalled the brew version and everything works now. Not sure what I installed with brew that installed python3 since it was already installed by apt but it was probably some side coding project thing so probably not important.
